# Error when trying to call a supabase edge function

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, supabase, deno, edge-function

I am trying to call a supabase edge function in javascript but I am getting this error:

> access to fetch at 'https:/blablala.functions.supabase.co/hello-world' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is how the function looks like (default when creating the function):

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts";

console.log("Hello from Functions!");

serve(async (req) => {
  const { name } = await req.json();
  const data = {
    message: `Hello ${name}!`,
  };

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
});
```

and this is how it looks when I try to call it (just like the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions)):

```
import { supabase } from "$lib/supabaseClient";

  const functionTest = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.functions.invoke("hello-world", {
      body: { name: "Functions" },
    });   };
```

I do not understand what the problem could be since this is just like they did in the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions). and I have no previous experience with edge/cloud functions so I have no idea how I could try to find a solution. I have not found any good recourses online either.

Comment: There is an additional step you have to take if you want to enable CORS on the browser. You can read the official guide on how to enable it https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/cors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to invoke a Supabase function from JS, but you haven't added the CORS headers to your function. [This link](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/cors) explains how to add CORS headers to your Supabase function.

Add this code to your `_shared` folder in `cors.ts`.

```js
export const corsHeaders = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'authorization, x-client-info, apikey, content-type',
}
```

Then, make your function like this:

```js
import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/http/server.ts'
import { corsHeaders } from '../_shared/cors.ts'

serve(async (req) => {
  // This is needed if you're planning to invoke your function from a browser.
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response('ok', { headers: corsHeaders })
  }

  try {

    // Function code here ...

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, // Be sure to add CORS headers here too
      status: 200,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, // and here
      status: 400,
    })
  }
})
```